# is there any way user can impersonate group in cq/AEM

Tags: aem, jcr

I am new to AEM. I was going through the impersonating functionality in useradmin.

[CQ documentation on impersonation](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/administering/security.html)

as per my understanding , impersonation can be done user to user. if there any way user can impersonate group i.e. if user-A can directly impersonate group-A with 5 user. As it would be really difficult for admin to impersonate every new user.

Please suggest

Comment: There is no way to impersonate group. Also, it does not make any sense to do this. Can you describe your use-case, probably, there is another way to do it?

Comment: Thanks for ur reply..

The requirement is that when author user lock a page then other user in admin category should unlock page. Can this be done using impersonation or is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: If you need to unlock pages really often, and you can not do it using "admin" account, I would write service, which does it for you (so you should not impersonate often). Unfortunately, I do not see any other solution there.